# Inspecting firmware integrity on Android

Tags: malware, device-firmware

How do I inspect the integrity of the firmware on my Android device? For instance, if a Remote Access Trojan is present, what steps should I take to detect and remove them?

Comment: Perform a factory reset and reinstall a full factory firmware image. That is the best option to make sure everything malicious is deleted.

Comment: some devices have option firmware integrity check in recovery menu, it will reveal at least system modifications. if integrity is intact a factory reset will remove possible malicious apps. remote access usually is granted by user, change your google account and password, revoke all device administators in settings, create new WhatsApp account, etc

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. My device, a Nokia 5.4 does not seem to have any options for checking firmware integrity. I can only see that the firmware version is the correct version as the one showed on the Nokia update tracker site - https://www.nokia.com/phones/en_int/security-updates. How do I obtain the factory firmware image?

Comment: That device is shipped with Android 10 and has unbreakable boot chain of trust. It can therefore considered as safe. Just do factory reset to be sure no user installed apps can harm, no need for firmware reinstall

Comment: @alexcs Thank you for that. I also want to check if Android 11 is vulnerable to the Pegasus malware? I'm aware that it targets both Android and iOS, but have only seen news about iOS so far. I understand this is because it's harder to detect Pegasus infections on Android. However, Apple just issued a patch for iOS, is a patch available for Android devices?